# насколько опасно установить opensuse rpm пакет на centos 6?

Tags: linux, centos, opensuse

В связи с тем, что под `centos` `package` не существует в сети нашёлся этот же `rpm` пакет но для дистрибутива `opensuse`

Интересует какие проблемы могут возникнуть если его установить на `centos 6` (собрав из исходников или установив уже собранный пакет)

Comment: целиком и полностью зависит от пакета. диапазон от «никаких проблем» до «вообще не установится, а при ручной распаковке архива перезапишет какие-нибудь файлы, что легко может вызвать неработоспособность каких-нибудь программ (вплоть до самых критически важных)».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin понятно спасибо

Comment: Пересобрать (перепаковать) религия позволяет? Тогда это самый лучший способ. А вообще для centos существует огромный репозиторий EPEL (fedora), там наверняка 95% пакетов найдёте.